# Nginx doesn't run server after docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm learning how to deploy web applications, I already did it once using, nginx and gunicorn and everything was perfect but now I had to do it using Docker and I'm stuck.

When I installed nginx without Docker I simply ran:

```
sudo systemctl start nginx
```

Then I went to my web-server and saw nginx running. But I do not understand it why I can't do it using docker-compose? I go to a specific url and nothing happens. When I access:

```
docker exec -ti nginx bash
```

it stays it doesn't know such commands as sudo, systemctl, start, etc.

What's the right way? I've read like 10 articles and still don't understand how to deploy and run my web-application (not on localhost though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you do not need to run systemctl in docker container
- just  `docker restart <container name>` will do the job ( if you want to restart nginx)
- you even dont need to use docker-compose to run nginx
- you can just run `docker run --name nginx -v /opt/nginx:/usr/share/nginx/html -p 8080:80 docker.io/nginx`

now curl `http://<you machine ip>:8080` should work

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to ssh into the nginx container and issue the `sudo systemctl start nginx command`. Once you start the container, nginx will start automatically.

This is a simple `docker-compose.yml` file starting nginx service:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginxserver:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - /opt/nginx:/usr/share/nginx/html:rw
```

Run the following command to start the service:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up
```

The service will start and it will be accesible on the localhost at `http://localhost:8080/` (see the port mapping section in the above yaml file)

See also the volume mapping section in the yaml file. The local directory `/opt/nginx` is mapped to the container directory `/usr/share/nginx/html`, which is the default nginx root directory.

Replace `/opt/nginx` with whatever local directory you want and just put a simple `index.html` file there for a test:

```
<html>
<body>
Hello world!
</body>
</html>
```

Now access `http://localhost:8080/` and you should see the Hello world message. Use that local directory to deploy your files.

Comment: Thank you for such a good explanation! But how can I run it in the web? I understand that it all does it locally, I mean it runs localhost. But since I'm trying to deploy, I need my server to be accessed via the ipv4. When I can simply do this without docker, just by running start nginx right after its installation. So how can I do the same using Docker?

Comment: Suppose that your server IP is a.b.c.d. Simply ssh to that, install docker and docker compose exactly as you did locally and use the same docker-compose.yml file. You will be able to access your application at http://a.b.c.d:8080/ Use the port 80 if that's only allowed but then change the "8080:80" definition from the docker-compose.yml with "80:80"

Comment: What's the difference between `docker-compose up` and `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up`?

Comment: @NoName No difference in this particular case, as docker compose will look for a default file named `docker-compose.yml` when the `-f` parameter doesn't specify a config file. But I think it is a good practice to always use the `-f` parameter to specify the config file. It might happen that the name of the config file to be different and mandatory to be specified when calling `docker-compose`. So if you are used to always specify it, you won't forget about it.